# Center EditText Horizontally in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, centering

I can't seem to center an EditText horizontally in a RelativeLayout. I have tried this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams editTextParams = ((RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editText.getLayoutParams());
        editTextParams.width = 400;
        editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
        editText.setLayoutParams(editTextParams);
```

Here is my layout XML file:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.app"
android:gravity="center_horizontal">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/usernameField"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="0dp"
    android:paddingEnd="0dp"
    android:hint="Enter username"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have also tried using the suggestion made by Trivial.

The above things just make the EditText stay left-aligned. I want the EditText to be centered.

Comment: Try in layout instead... using {android:layout_centerHorizontal}.

Comment: I have to do it programatically.

Comment: Try `editTextParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);`

Comment: That didn't work. Thanks for trying, though!

Comment: Post your entire layout structure so we can help. What are in RelativeLayout?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

Add this to the edittext xml

Comment: I have to do it programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that

`android:paddingStart="10dp"` and     `android:paddingEnd="0dp"` is interfering somewhere.

Try removing it and tell us the result?